# Cannot run android app using expo because of Kotlin Gradle plugin version conflict

Tags: react-native, expo, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I created an expo project and ran `expo run:android`.
And android project is built, but Gradle fails due to a version conflict.
This is the message that I got.

```bash
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.4.1
Gradle: 7.5.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project '(app name)' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I can directly fix `build.gradle` file to resolve this issue.
But, this approach will still create build fails for eas build, because prebuilt files will not be changed.

How can I make expo to create android files with correct gradle plugin version?

Comment: What do you mean by „prebuilt files will not be changed.“?

Comment: @MichaelBahl Prebuilt files are native codes created from react-native codes, and `build.gradle` is part of them. So if I don't change the expo codes and modify `build.gradle`, the expo will create the wrong `build.gradle` again with `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10` during eas build and will fail again.

Comment: Does ```npx expo prebuild``` work?
Does ./gradlew :app:assembleRelease work ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl Thanks for your reply. I found out the cause. I was using `@react-native-seoul/kakao-login` plugin, and it kept re-setting the kotlin-gradle plugin version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by:

1. You can fork https://github.com/crossplatformkorea/react-native-kakao-login
2. Change kotlin-gradle plugin version
3. Add your fork to you package.json